# MultiLevel Grouping Grid for GXT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

This demo [here](http://www.sencha.com/examples/pages/grid/grouping.html) in GXT showcase shows a grid with one level of grouping. 
 Is there any open source solution for Multilevel grouping Grid on GXT ?

Answer (score 0):

For multilevel grouping you can use GXT TreeGrid. 
 Here is a tutorial about TreeGrid

http://zawoad.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-create-basic-treegrid-using.html

Comment: we cannot do grouping in a TreeGrid